# Automatically activate "button2" click after a click on button "button1"

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to activate button2 click after button1 click. Made a click function an set it on button 1 in a onclick. After clicking on button1 nothing happens, button2 is not clicked automatically

Code of `button1` :

```html
<button onclick="clickButton()" style="visibility: hidden" id="button1" 
  class="testClass" name="testName" value="{{ object.pk }}" 
  type="submit">Button1</button>
```

Code of `button2`, in a form :

```html
<form  id="onderteken_pdf_contract" >
  <button style="margin-left: 40px" id="button2" 
    name="arbeidscontract_id" type="submit" 
    class="maakVacatureButton">Button2</button>
</form>
```

JavaScript code :

```js
function clickButton(){
  document.getElementById("button2").click();
}
```

Comment: look it, pls - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/how-to-trigger-event-in-javascript

Comment: yes, but the .click() has to work in my opinion but i cant get it to work. I just dont get it

Comment: I have checked your code and the code works.

Comment: what do you expect to happen?

Comment: I shortened the code , maybe thats the problem. After click on button2 there is a post request to django. This is not working. If i click (not automated) on button2 the request is made.

Comment: I managed it in the backend, still confused why this is not working in html/javascript